# Showing a modal in browser after a certain time of user session activity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an app in Django 1.7 but I think that might not be so relevant to the question.

What I am trying to do is that when a user comes to my app, I let him/her play around the website for sometime. However, after a fixed time of activity (say 1 minute) or a fixed number of interactions (say 5 links clicked), I would like to show a message or a modal to the user to get feedback, or to remind user to log in.

I think this would need to be done in JavaScript, but I am not entirely sure how to do it. How do I track a user session through different pages of the website, and then trigger a modal/message show automatically?

Comment: do you mean x amount of time on one page or x amount of time on the website?

Comment: @dlkulp x amount of time total on the website

Comment: Using a session cookie that stores the time of first page load _and/or_ a cookie that counts the number of reloads?

Comment: yea, cookies or localstorage is probably the easiest way to do this unless you're running server side stuff like node or php

Comment: Ok, so for every new request I get, I store the time in session cookie, and then add a timeout in javascript using the time set in the cookie to show the message after the timeout? Since I am using persistent sessions, maybe @dlkulp suggestion of using localstorage will be better than using cookies?

Comment: You can't use `setTimeout()` if you want it to work accross pages

Comment: You could use `setTimout()` to check the against the cookie/localstorage within one page but you'd need to do that on every page, ie: you can't start a `setTimout()` on the home page and expect it to work when they click the contact link unless you start a new interval on the contact page as well

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you check if cookie `sessionstart` is set, if not you store the current time in it (I.e. In milliseconds). The you do something like

```
var time = ...;// read from cookie here
setTimeout(function(){
    if(new Date().getTime() - time > youPopupDelay){
        alert("time is over");
    }
},1000);
```

There are probably tons of source how to read write from cookie, but that would address your session issue and while I use alert you can of course do something more sophisticated.